# nhibernate <bag> exception - illegal access to loading collection

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am getting "illegal access to loading collection" exception while trying to populate "IList" property in Supplier Domain using NHibernate . I have tried all suggestions I got by googling but nothing seems to help :(

Here are my domain objects and .HBM files. I would greatly appreciate your help/suggestions.

## Supplier Domain Object

```
namespace Inventory.DomainObjects
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Supplier
    {
        public virtual string SupplierID { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Address> Address { get; set; }

    }
}
```

## Address Domain Object

```
namespace Inventory.DomainObjects
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Address 
    {
        public virtual int AddressID { get; set; }
        public virtual string SupplierID { get; set; }

        public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Line2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Line3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Supplier.HBM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="Inventory.DomainObjects"
                   assembly="Inventory">
  <class name="Supplier" table="Inv_Supplier">
    <id name="SupplierID" column="SupplierId" type="string"/>

    <property name="SupplierCode" column="Code" type="string"/>
    <property name="Name" column="SupplierName" type="string"/>
    <property name="Description" column="SupplierDescription" type="string"/>

    <bag name="Address" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="true">
      <key column="SupplierID" not-null="true"/>
      <one-to-many class="Address" not-found="ignore"/>
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

## Address.HBM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="Inventory.DomainObjects"
                   assembly="Inventory">
  <class name="Address" table="Inv_Supplier_Address" lazy="false">
    <id name="AddressID" column="AddressId" type="integer"/>

    <property name="Line1" column="Line1" type="string"/>
    <property name="Line2" column="Line2" type="string"/>
    <property name="Line3" column="Line3" type="string"/>

    <many-to-one name="SupplierID" column="SupplierId" not-null="true" class="Supplier" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

```
<many-to-one name="SupplierID" column="SupplierId" 
       not-null="true" class="Supplier" />
```

Could you try removing the above line to see if the problem goes away?

If this fixes the problem you should add the `many-to-one` back as follows:

```
namespace Inventory.DomainObjects
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Address 
    {
        public virtual int AddressID { get; set; }

        // CHANGED: reference supplier object instead of ID
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; } 

        public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Line2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Line3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then change your hbm mapping file like this (to reference the `Supplier` property instead of `SupplierId`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="Inventory.DomainObjects"
                   assembly="Inventory">
  <class name="Address" table="Inv_Supplier_Address" lazy="false">
    <id name="AddressID" column="AddressId" type="integer"/>

    <property name="Line1" column="Line1" type="string"/>
    <property name="Line2" column="Line2" type="string"/>
    <property name="Line3" column="Line3" type="string"/>

    <many-to-one name="Supplier" column="SupplierId" 
             not-null="true" class="Supplier" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks much Andy. Your suggestion worked. Silly me, I didn't noticed that :( Is it possible to populate a List Property in Supplier Object (IList<Image> Images) from another table (Inv_Images) which contains NO PRIMARY KEY but contains multiple images for an Supplier with SupplierId as Foreign Key? I am unable to define a HBM Mapping file for Image table containing NO Primary Key.